# MVCContrib pager with large number of query parameters and URL routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a search controller that has a large number of parameters (the search criteria). I want to page through the results using MVCContrib - IPagination. This is all good the problem is how to generate the Link on the Html.Pager. I've tried this in the view

> @Html.Pager(Model.Results).Link(p =>
>   Url.Action("Search", new {
>   Model.Criteria } ))

but is doesn't work. Do I need to register a route so that the Url.Action understands how to form the link?

Controller code below....

```
public ViewResult Search(JobSearch search, int? page, IAuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser)
    {
        // perform search
        var query = _jobRepository.CreateQuery<IPagedJobSearch>();

        query.SiteId = authenticatedUser.SiteId;
        query.JobId = search.Criteria.JobId;
        query.Lot = search.Criteria.LotNumber;
        query.Street = search.Criteria.StreetInfo.Name;
        query.StreetNumber = search.Criteria.StreetInfo.Number;
        query.Suburb = search.Criteria.Suburb;
        query.Council = search.Criteria.Council;
        query.ClientRef = search.Criteria.ClientOrderNumber;
        query.ItemsPerPage = 15;
        query.PageNumber = page ?? 1;

        var pagedResult = query.Execute(); ......
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't show all of your markup but you'll need to specify each of your parameters like this:

```
  <%= Html.Pager(Model.AssetsPagedList)
        .First("First")
        .Last("Last")
        .Next("Next")
        .Previous("Previous")
          .Link(currentPage => Url.Action("Browse", new {  
            page = currentPage,
            searchTerm = Model.SearchModel.SearchTerm,
            excludedWords = Model.SearchModel.ExcludedWords,
            minPrice = Model.SearchModel.MinPrice,
            maxPrice = Model.SearchModel.MaxPrice,
            locationId = Model.SearchModel.LocationId,  
            catalogId = Model.SearchModel.CatalogId
        })) 
        %>
```

Once you have the correct parameters, you'll need to create a controller that accepts each of them:

```
public ActionResult Browse(int? id, string searchTerm, int? locationId,
    GridSortOptions gridSortOptions, int? page, string excludedWords, 
    decimal? minPrice, decimal? maxPrice, int? catalogId)
{

}
```

Comment: I was hoping to not list all parameters and get model binding to use my criteria object, (which has all the params).

Comment: You can ask on the MVCContrib site but it doesn't support that as far as I know